# Minecraft modding 1.7.10 textures not showing

Tags: java, textures, minecraft

I am making a mod and i am getting this error:

> Using missing texture, unable to load null:textures/items/TrainingCorpsBoots.png
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: null:textures/items/TrainingCorpsBoots.png

I have the texture name set as exactly the above and in the folder items.

This is my code:

```
package com.example.AoT;

import javax.swing.text.html.parser.Entity;

import scala.tools.nsc.MainClass;
import net.minecraft.creativetab.CreativeTabs;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemArmor;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemArmor.ArmorMaterial;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;

public class ArmorTC extends ItemArmor{

public ArmorTC(int i, ArmorMaterial armorTC, int id, int placement) {
super(armorTC, id, placement);
setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabCombat);

if (placement == 1){
    this.setTextureName(AoT.TrainingCorpsJacket + ":TrainingCorpsJacket");
}   
else if (placement == 2){
        this.setTextureName(AoT.TrainingCorpsTrousers + ":TrainingCorpsTrousers");
}       
else if (placement == 3){
            this.setTextureName(AoT.TrainingCorpsBoots + ":TrainingCorpsBoots");
}
}
public String getArmorTexture(ItemStack stack, Entity entity, int slot, String type) {
    if (stack.getItem() == AoT.TrainingCorpsJacket || stack.getItem() ==        AoT.TrainingCorpsBoots) {
        return AoT.MODID + ":textures/models/armor/Clothes.png";
}
    if (stack.getItem() ==  AoT.TrainingCorpsTrousers) {
        return AoT.MODID + ":textures/models/armor/Clothes2.png";
    }   else {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

I changed this part

```
if (placement == 1){
    this.setTextureName(AoT.MODID + ":TrainingCorpsJacket");
}   
else if (placement == 2){
        this.setTextureName(AoT.MODID + ":TrainingCorpsTrousers");
}       
else if (placement == 3){
        this.setTextureName(AoT.MODID + ":TrainingCorpsBoots");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `setTextureName()` you're passing it:

```
AoT.TrainingCorpsBoots + ":TrainingCorpsBoots"
```

As it's an Item, `TrainingCorpsBoots` part will be expanded to:

```
TrainingCorpsBoots
TrainingCorpsBoots.png
textures/items/TrainingCorpsBoots.png
```

And you're passing the colon (`:`) yourself, so `AoT.TrainingCorpsBoots` must therefore be `null`.

You should be using:

```
this.setTextureName(AoT.MODID + ":TrainingCorpsBoots");
```

And make sure the file is present at `mymod/textures/items/TrainingCorpsBoots.png` (where `mymod` is whatever `AoT.MODID` is assigned to.

Comment: Hmm, what should I change in the code then? Sorry but I'm new to coding.

Comment: :/ still not working image is at MOD\src\main\resources\assets\AoT\textures\items

Comment: I had to change the folder name (mymod) from AoT to aot (all lowercase) i don't get why though.